# T-s diagram of hydrogen

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

I'm searching for a T-s chart of hydrogen in the range (0 .. 200 degC, 0 .. 300 bar). (example for nitrogen see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect#/media/File:Throttling_in_Ts_diagram_01.jpg)

To my supprise I was not sucessfull with googeling.

Any idea where to find, download? Moderate pricing (eg. 30 USD) would be ok.

Or can someone help me with the following (No, this is not my homework)?

What's the temperature change, if you expand isenthalpic:

- from 25 degC, 300 bar   to 30 bar
- from 25 degC, 300 bar   to 5 bar
- from 25 degC, 30 bar   to 5 bar

How much heating/cooling do you require per kg H2, if you want to bring it back to 25 degC after that?

Comment: Why do you need a TS diagram for this?

Comment: I would think that a PH diagram would be more appropriate for this.

Comment: To my understanding t-s is a more common representation. Do you have a link to a p-h diagramm?

Comment: To my understanding h-p diagram is much more common.  Just Google "pressure enthalpy diagram for hydrogen".  You can also calculate the answer if you know Cp in the ideal gas region and have either an equation of state for hydrogen or a generalized corresponding states residual enthalpy diagram as a function of reduced temperature and pressure.

Comment: https://h2tools.org/hyarc/hydrogen-data/hydrogen-enthalpy-different-temperatures-and-pressures